# Best way to set Scaffold ThemeData based on SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter

I have a String in the shared_preferences plugin that stores a particular ThemeData widget.  What/where is the best way to read out of the shared_preferences plugin to pull that String so that the ThemeData for the entire app can be set? This is during app startup.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setting page to save and get data

```
 saveprefs(bool val) async {
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 // checkfont = val;
 // prefs.setBool("checkfont", checkfont);
 getprefs();
 } // save sharde

 getprefs() async {     
 /*    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();              
 checkfont = prefs.getBool("checkfont");
 if (checkfont == true) {
 myfont = 18;
 prefs.setDouble("myfont", 18);
 } else {
 myfont = 16;
  prefs.setDouble("myfont", 16);
      }*/
```

after save in setting page you can call data  in another page

```
 getsharedpref() async {
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 myfont = prefs.getDouble("myfont");
 return myfont;
 } // get SharedPreferences
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve this by reading SharedPrefs before runApp().
Did something like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //Pull ThemeData() object from SharedPrefs here using 'await'
  runApp();
}
```